# ¿Como se representan Atributos Multivaluadas en Diagrama Entidad Relacion?

Tags: base-de-datos, diagrama-er

Estoy haciendo una base de datos para una plataforma web de streaming de clases en linea para mi universidad, pero me surgió una duda ¿Cómo se representan los atributos multivaluados que tienen mas atributos en un Diagrama de Entidad Relacion? por ejemplo Una clase puede tener N numero de Videos guardados, al igual una clase puede tener N numero de Horarios, El alumno puede tener N numero de clases con su calificación y todo, al igual el profesor puede tener N numero de clases y saber que alumnos estan inscritos a cada clase, aqui un ejemplo de como hice una parte del diagrma: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es esta bien el diagrama en el atributo Horarios, la relacion Cursa y videos?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tu buscas no debería simplemente realizarse, un atributo con multivalores infringe las reglas de normalización, puedes consultar las reglas en el siguiente enlace:

[Base de datos - primera Forma Normal](http://cidecame.uaeh.edu.mx/lcc/mapa/PROYECTO/libro14/421_primera_forma_normal.html)

El correcto diseño de una base de datos no debería incluir datos multivalorados ya que este puede generar inconsistencia de datos y evitar la atomicidad de los mismos. A continuación presento un ejemplo abordando tu ejemplo anterior, donde se observa que la tabla "clase" contiene videos de una manera incorrecto y de lado izquierdo la manera correcta en la que este dato debería ser normalizado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]